# Login Forms for Hotmail Website using Mechanize/Python

Tags: python, forms, urllib2, mechanize, www-mechanize

I'm learning Mechanize/BeautifulSoup by following the instruction on this site: http://stockrt.github.io/p/handling-html-forms-with-python-mechanize-and-BeautifulSoup/

Instead of writing a login and check mail for Gmail, I want to do the same for hotmail. However, I cannot find the login form by using Mechanize. The result when im trying to do the following is empty:

```
for f in self.br.forms():
  print 'form:', f
```

Those codes print out nothing. By inspecting the hotmail website (login.live.com) I can see the form name is 'F1' and 2 fields are 'username' and 'passwd' but Mechanize cannot be able to catch those.

Here is the complete code:

```
import os
import mechanize
import cookielib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import html2text
import agent

class Hotmail:
    def __init__(self):
        self.br = mechanize.Browser()
        cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()     # Cookie Jar
        self.br.set_cookiejar(cj)
        # Browser options
        self.br.set_handle_equiv(True)
        #self.br.set_handle_gzip(True)
        self.br.set_handle_redirect(True)
        self.br.set_handle_referer(True)
        self.br.set_handle_robots(False)

        self.br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)   # Follows refresh 0 but not hangs on refresh > 0
        self.br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]                       # User-Agent

    def login(self, user, pswd):
        self.br.open('http://login.live.com')
        for f in self.br.forms():
            print 'form:', f

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test = Hotmail()
    test.login('asd','asd')
```

I also tried to manually set the form 'F1' to br.form and fill out the values for it, but it doesn't work.

Any ideas why Mechanize cannot recognize any forms on Hotmail or how to get those forms?

Thank you so much!

Comment: I think that form doesn't exist in the returned HTML. It's constructed with JavaScript.

Comment: is it any possible way that we can trigger the javascript and get the forms to fill?